# can you have multiple RDFa's on a website if the company has multiple locations?

Tags: seo, rdfa

I am working with a company who has multiple locations across the state. I am trying to get them listed higher on Google Places. Google recommended inserting RFDa's into the index page.

Does anyone know if you can have multiple RDFA's describing all locations on the index page?

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure whether Google supports it, RDFa allows you to include as many entities as you like on a page. It is a good idea to have separate identifiers (`about` attribute) for them, like:

```
<div xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#">
    <p typeof="v:Organization" about="#helsinki">
        <!-- Address of Helsinki office -->
    </p>
    <p typeof="v:Organization" about="#ny">
        <!-- Address of New York office -->
    </p>
</div>
```

If this was placed on a page behind address `http://example.net/`, then the URIs for the offices would be `http://example.net/#helsinki` and `http://example.net/#ny`, which are unique even though on same page.